# Move Git Branches Locally

Tags: git, github, branch

I have created multiple repos locally of the same remote repo. Lets say repo1 and repo2 are the 2 repos that are local on my hard disk. Both these have different branches for different fixes that I had done (Say A1, A2 in repo1 and B1, B2, B3 in repo2).

Now, I want to move all the branches from repo2 to repo1 only locally so that I can delete repo2 and save some space on the hard disk. I want all the history of the branches to be migrated only locally for future reference.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Since Git is peer-to-peer, any clone can act as a "remote" for any other clone (assuming there is a network connection between the two).

So simply add `repo2` as a remote for `repo1`, then create local branches as you normally would:

```
cd <path-to-repo1>
git remote add repo2 <path-to-repo2>
git fetch repo2
git checkout <branch-to-preserve>
git checkout <branch-to-preserve>
# ... etc
```